# Extract minimum value in frame row if not 0 in R

Tags: r, apply, minimum

I would like to identify whether all of the values in a row are 0 and if so, return 0, otherwise return the minimum value in the row that is not 0. For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,0), y = c(0,1,0), z = c(0,0,2))
```

Here, I would like the function to return the vector (0,1,2,). I've tried something like this, but it doesn't get there:

```
apply(dat,1, function(x) ifelse(x==0, 0, min(x)[x!=0]))
```

Any and all thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can change waht you did to:

```
apply(dat,1, function(x) ifelse(sum(x)==0, 0, min(x[x!=0])))
[1] 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
indx <- !!rowSums(dat!=0)
is.na(dat[indx,]) <- dat[indx,]==0
do.call(pmin, c(dat, na.rm=TRUE))
#[1] 0 1 2
```

Or without changing the original dataset

```
library(car)
recode(do.call(pmin, c((NA^!dat)*dat, na.rm=TRUE)), 'NA=0')
#[1] 0 1 2
```